# geocode_OSM() in R returning $query = NA fails in a loop but works by itself

Tags: r

I have a script that uses tmaptools::geocode_OSM() in a loop.

Here is said loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) {
if(origAddress[i,'lon'] == ""){
print(
  paste(
    "Working on geocoding:"
    , origAddress$PartialAddress[i]
    )
  )
result <- geocode_OSM(
  origAddress$PartialAddress[i]
  , return.first.only = T
  , as.data.frame = T
)
origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[3])
origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
} else {
print("Trying next record...")
}
}
```

This loop works fine until it gets to something where `geocode_OSM()$query`returns `NA` for some reason the loop breaks down. The example I am working with is a parital address where the town is spelt wrong. The result of the loop returns:

```
Error in do.call(rbind, output3) : second argument must be a list
In addition: Warning message:
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : No results found for "LAKE RONKONKAMA, NY, 11779".
```

Above LAKE RONKONKAMA is actually spelt LAKE RONKONKOMA.  When I run the following outside of a loop I get:

```
tst.rslt <- geocode_OSM(
  origAddress$PartialAddress["LAKE RONKONKAMA, NY, 11779"]
  , return.first.only = T
  , as.data.frame = T
)
print(tst.rslt)

 query      lat      lon  lat_min  lat_max  lon_min  lon_max
1  <NA> 64.57315 11.52804 57.75901 71.38488 4.087527 31.76149
```